# kernel-cfs : Why is LOAD_AVG_MAX 47742?

Tags: kernel, cfs

In PELT of CFS, below parameters are used for calculating PELT.

"#define LOAD_AVG_MAX 47742 /* maximum possible load avg */"

"#define LOAD_AVG_MAX_N 345 /* number of full periods to produce LOAD_AVG_MAX */"

Why is the LOAD_AVG_MAX 47742 ?

Why is the LOAD_AVG_MAX_N 345 ?

I cannot find the exact explanation about these parameters. 
Could you explain it in detail ?